# Short keyboard combination to enter an en dash in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: windows, keyboard, libreoffice-writer

In LibreOffice Writer on Windows 10 Pro, to get an en dash it's possible to use Autocorrect and "--", and it's also possible to call Unicode and type "2013" Alt+x. I don't use Autocorrect. The second method is okay, but it's lengthy. Is there a shorter keyboard combination, similar to Alt+- in Microsoft Word (where "-" is the minus on the numberpad)?

Comment: In my Kubuntu the keystroke to get `–` is AltGr+`-` and it works in all programs because the keyboard layout (Polish in my case) is nice enough to handle this *out of the box*. I think a keyboard layout rich in such symbols is a neat way, programs don't need to care about `–`, `…`, `²` etc. each for itself (e.g. I have typed all these into my browser just like I can type `ó` or `ś`). What is your OS? Some details of your question make me believe it's Windows, but this should be explicitly stated (e.g. by adding a proper tag). Please [edit] the question and add this information.

Answer (score 0):

For a single character like the en dash, you can:

1. record a macro in which the en dash is added using the combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> (that is, hold down the Alt key while typing the four numbers on the keypad),
2. go to `Tools > Customize > Keyboard`, and
3. modify a desired Shortcut Key to run the recorded macro (which should be buried someplace in the "Application Macros" category).

*Notes*

- Use of <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> will result in a macro that inserts `2013` rather than `–`.
- It may be necessary to go to `Tools > Options > Advanced` and check `Enable macro recording` under the heading "Optional Features" for macro recording to be available.